# Haskell difference in showing Data.Text

Tags: haskell, text

Consider the next code in `GHCi`:

```
*> data R = R { s :: Text }
*> instance Show R where show x = unpack $ s x
*> let r = R $ pack "¶"
*> r
¶
*> s r
"\182"
```

Why does it shows the paragraph sign without the quotes and when showing `R` datatype. And showing like `[Char]` (actually, `:t s r` is `Text`) when showing `s r`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Show` instance for `R` says "when I want to show an `R`, print this string", and returns the actual `Text` value. If you *wanted* this to have quote marks, you need to explicitly add them.

By contrast, `s r` is just a `Text` value. It shows the way `Text` always shows (identical to `String`, apparently).

Think about the instance for `Show Int`, if that makes more sense. When you do `show 5`, it returns a string that only contains a `5` character. When you do `show "5"`, it returns a string containing three characters - a quote, a five, and a quote.